# How to create a new folder in system with a name same as the string that is available at a specific page on webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My requirement is I should be able to create new folder from chrome some how by specific name. To be specific, I visit salesforce everyday for my work and there will be different ticket numbers with description. I create manual folder to save ticket files on system drive every time I get new ticket. I imagine there should be some action of folder creation at the right click of that selected text.

[Expecting something similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvq2t.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interface with the operating system and create folders, you would need to use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/). Native Messaging allows you to communicate a native program via stdin and stdout protocols. Your native program will then accept commands that tell it to create that folder.

Here is an example extension that uses `nativeMessaging` https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/mv2-archive/api/nativeMessaging

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. I will try to understand this extension and would take a time because I know only basics of any kind of development.

Comment: Hi @Mohamed, thank you for your help. I have referred to one video and performed steps as per the guide. I am explaining what I did via image on this URL. In the end I want to create a  folder using "mkdir C:\new folder" in .bat file. If I execute this bat file from file explorer it creates the folder but not via the button that popup from extension. Can you check this image and suggest me what can be done as a part of troubleshooting. How can I track where it is broken.

https://imgur.com/JvXbYhC